# Наследование файлов C#

Tags: c#

Не могу наследовать файл в осн[image: введите сюда описание изображения]овной. Обрыл инет, но ничего не нашел.

Comment: Судя по фото - я бы **настоятельно** рекомендовал почитать для начала книги по ЯП!

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Книги и учебные ресурсы по C#](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/416584/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%be-c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы метод с классом перепутали.

Вот класс:

```cs
public class MyClass : InstallerCloth
{
    public MyClass()
    {
    }
}
```

А вот метод:

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var instance = new MyClass();
    // ...
}
```

Вам надо учить синтаксис языка. Сейчас вы пишете код вслепую, а это очень сложно делать.

- [Классы и объекты](https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/3.1.php)
- [Наследование](https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/3.7.php)

P.S. Файл - это такая штука, на диске хранится. К C# наследованию она не имеет отношения.